# Create Journey Builder folder by API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, soap-api

I am trying to create a Journey Builder Folder by Rest or Soap API but I couldn't find a solution.

I found this API route by looking at Chrome inspector : `https://jbinteractions.s6.marketingcloudapps.com/fuelapi/platform-internal/v1/categories/`

But seems that it is not part of the Journey Builder Public API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make a Journey Builder folder by REST (and likely via SOAP as well).

I tend towards REST so my solution is going to be using the REST API. It is not a documented endpoint (so all those disclaimers apply - not supported, can disappear at any moment, etc. etc) but it seems something stable and safe to utilize.

Using this endpoint along with the proper payload will allow you to build your folder.

```
POST /email/v1/Category
Host: {{tse}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_Token}}

{
    "ParentCatId": {{parentCategoryID}},
    "Name": "Rest_Created",
    "CatType": "journey"
}
```

Utilizing the above, switching out the placeholders for real values, will give you what you need to create a folder in SFMC Journey Builder.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works also from /email/v1/categories. I found that the GET {{hostEndpoint}}/email/v1/categories?CatType=journey retreives the top folder and GET {{hostEndpoint}}/email/v1/categories/{{CattegoryId}} to retreive a specific folder. But PUT, PATCH and DELETE routes don't seem to exist. Maybe you came across them? Thanks again!

Comment: @Gortonington brilliant, thanks for sharing. Out of curiosity and besides using the network tab in debug mode of the browser, how did you find this endpoint?

Comment: @RachidMamai - The discovery endpoint (/rest) on each 'group' helps as well. e.g. `interaction/v1/rest` will return all the endpoints on that group. Can do for the other ones as well. That, the UI and just plain trial and error are the ways I dig in to see what is available.

Comment: @Gortonington I see, I didn't know about that. Thanks a lot!